# Method Export of object '_Chart' failed Run-time error -2147286987 80030035

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have setup a macro assigned to a button to push a daily report to a SharePoint site. I can run the procedure and so can another user on a different computer in a different location. Two other users on separate computers in the same location cannot and get 'Run-time error -2147286987 (80030035) Method Export of object '_Chart' failed. I am at a complete loss. If those same users go into the SharePoint and manually save the same bmp to the same location they have no issues. All references are also the same. I thought it was a permissions issue but that does not appear to be the case. Any help is appreciated.

It is failing on this line:

```
.Chart.Export "\\sharepoint-dns.com\sites\oursharepoint\SiteAssets\SitePages\Dashboard\" & sFile & ".bmp", "BMP"
```

Full VBA is shown below. PublishSharePoint calls SaveImage

```
Sub PublishSharePoint()

'User cell selection when running macro
Dim iRowRef As Integer
Dim iColRef As Integer
Dim iLastRow As Integer

SheetRef = ActiveSheet.Name
iRowRef = ActiveCell.Row
iColRef = ActiveCell.Column

'Unprotect Sheet
'Worksheets("Dashboard_3").Unprotect

Call SaveImage("Dashboard_3", "B5:O76", "Dashboard")

'Protect Sheet
'Worksheets("Dashboard_3").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

'Return to starting cell
Worksheets(SheetRef).Activate
Cells(iRowRef, iColRef).Select

End Sub
```

...

```
Sub SaveImage(sSheet As String, sRange As String, sFile As String)

Worksheets(sSheet).Activate

Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheet).Range(sRange)

Plage.CopyPicture

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)
.Activate
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
'.Chart.Export "C:\...\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
'.Chart.Export "C:\...\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
.Chart.Export "\\sharepoint-dns.com\sites\oursharepoint\SiteAssets\SitePages\Dashboard\" & sFile & ".bmp", "BMP"
End With

Worksheets(sSheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(sSheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

Set Plage = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough to explain the root cause in detail but this seems to be related to the webdav path requiring network credentials in some instances. As a work around I mapped the SharePoint path as a network drive and this works for all users.

```
Dim oNetwork As Object
Set oNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
oNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "http://sharepoint-dns.com/sites/oursharepoint/SiteAssets/SitePages/Dashboard", False
```

remember to disconnect the drive...

```
oNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:"
```